# Is there a way to get datum names from c3 data.columns?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

Using this [example](http://c3js.org/samples/data_label_format.html) for reference.

Is there away to assign label formatting without knowing the datum name?

In the example below, the datum names are data1,data2, and data3, but I'm trying to format without hardcoding the name.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
data: {
    columns: [
        ['data1', 30, -200, -100, 400, 150, 250],
        ['data2', -50, 150, -150, 150, -50, -150],
        ['data3', -100, 100, -40, 100, -150, -50]
    ],
    type: 'bar',
    labels: {
        format: {
            data1: d3.format('$'),
        }
    }
},
grid: {
    y: {
        lines: [{value: 0}]
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [pass a function](http://c3js.org/reference.html#data-labels-format) instead of an object to `data.labels.format`.
In you case that would be

```
labels: {
    format: d3.format('$'),
}
```